# Missing statement block switch causing script to error out

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am writing this powershell script for automating TFS deployment. Here is the section of the script that is throwing the error Missing statement block in switch statement clause. The syntax looks correct to me but I can't seem to resolve the error. Any ideas?

```
function core ([string]$EnVar)
    {

# Set the build parameters
    $params="environment="+$EnVar+";SQLServer="+$SQLServer+";IISServer="+$IISServer+";DBName="+$DBName

    write-output $params >> $OutputFile

    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe $DeploymentScript /p:$params >> $OutputFile 2>&1

    write-output $params >> $OutputFile
    write-output $LastExitCode >> $OutputFile

if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    write-output "An error has occured." >> $OutputFile
    $outline = "Updating build quality to Failed " + $Environment + " Deployment." 
    write-output $outline >> $OutputFile

    switch ($EnVar)
    {
        "Test" {$build.Quality = "Failed Test Deployment"}
        "Stage" {$build.Quality = "Failed Stage Deployment"}
        "Prod" {$build.Quality = "Failed Production Deployment"}
        default {$build.Quality = "Rejected"} 
    }
    $build.Save()

     $cmdLine = "/ID 2 /L ""Operation Logs"" /T ERROR /SO $tfsProject.DeployTo$EnVar /D ""($buildNumber) deployed by ($requestedby) FAILED! Deployment log file: $OutputFile """
    invoke-expression "$tool $cmdline"
    write-output "Sending failure email." >> $OutputFile
    $to = $emailRequestedBy
    $body = "<html>Deployment log file: """+ $OutputFile + """</html>"
    $subject = $tfsProject + " " + $EnVar + " Deployment failed"
    send-SMTPmail -to $to -from "tfsservice@vistex.com" -subject $subject -html -body $body
    exit(1)
}
else 
{
    $outline = "Successfully deployed to " + $EnVar + "."
    write-output $outline >> $OutputFile
    $outline = "Updating build quality to Deployed to " + $EnVar + "."
    write-output $outline >> $OutputFile

    switch ($EnVar)
    {   
        "Test" ($build.Quality = "Deployed to Test"}
        "Stage" {$build.Quality = "Deployed to Stage"}
        "Prod" {$build.Quality = "Deployed to Production"}
        default {$build.Quality = "Rejected"} 
    }

    $build.Save()
    $cmdLine = "/ID 1 /L ""Operation Logs"" /T SUCCESS /SO $tfsProject.DeployTo$EnVar /D ""($buildNumber) deployed by $requestedby successfully finish. Deployment log file: $OutputFile """
    invoke-expression "$tool $cmdline"
    write-output "Sending success email." >> $OutputFile
    $to = $emailRequestedBy
    $body = "<html>Deployment log file: """+ $OutputFile + """</html>"
    $subject = $tfsProject + " " + $EnVar + " Deployment successfully completed"
    send-SMTPmail -to $to -from "tfsservice@vistex.com" -subject $subject -html -body $body
} 
}
```

Comment: The error is in the switch statement in the script. It keeps throwing the error Missing statement block in switch statement clause.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. It's a typo... You have a `(` instead of a `{` in the "Test" case:

```
else 
{
    $outline = "Successfully deployed to " + $EnVar + "."
    write-output $outline >> $OutputFile
    $outline = "Updating build quality to Deployed to " + $EnVar + "."
    write-output $outline >> $OutputFile
    switch ($EnVar)
    {   
        "Test" ($build.Quality = "Deployed to Test"}
        "Stage" {$build.Quality = "Deployed to Stage"}
        "Prod" {$build.Quality = "Deployed to Production"}
        default {$build.Quality = "Rejected"} 
    }
```

Update the line to be:

```
        "Test" {$build.Quality = "Deployed to Test"}
```